# Flutter/ My app can't load to emulator or real device?

Tags: android, firebase, flutter, runtime-error, build.gradle

I want to work with firebase and I changed build.gradle docs then when i try to run flutter app i see this commands in debug console.

> ```
>   Launching lib\main.dart on Google Pixel in debug mode...
>     √ Built build\app\outputs\flutter-apk\app-debug.apk.
>     Exited (1)
> ```

android/app/build.gradle :

```
def localProperties = new Properties()
def localPropertiesFile = rootProject.file('local.properties')
if (localPropertiesFile.exists()) {
    localPropertiesFile.withReader('UTF-8') { reader ->
        localProperties.load(reader)
    }
}

def flutterRoot = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.sdk')
if (flutterRoot == null) {
    throw new FileNotFoundException("Flutter SDK not found. Define location with flutter.sdk in the local.properties file.")
}

def flutterVersionCode = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionCode')
if (flutterVersionCode == null) {
    flutterVersionCode = '1'
}

def flutterVersionName = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionName')
if (flutterVersionName == null) {
    flutterVersionName = '1.0'
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply from: "$flutterRoot/packages/flutter_tools/gradle/flutter.gradle"

android {
    compileSdkVersion 29

    sourceSets {
        main.java.srcDirs += 'src/main/kotlin'
    }

    lintOptions {
        disable 'InvalidPackage'
    }

    defaultConfig {
        // TODO: Specify your own unique Application ID (https://developer.android.com/studio/build/application-id.html).
        applicationId "com.connect_play"
        minSdkVersion 23
        targetSdkVersion 29
        versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
        versionName flutterVersionName
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJunitRunner"
        multiDexEnabled true
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            // TODO: Add your own signing config for the release build.
            // Signing with the debug keys for now, so `flutter run --release` works.
            signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
        }
    }
}

flutter {
    source '../..'
}

dependencies {

    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:17.4.4'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:runner:1.1.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.1.1'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

android/build.gradle :

```
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.3.72'
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.3'
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.0'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}

rootProject.buildDir = '../build'
subprojects {
    project.buildDir = "${rootProject.buildDir}/${project.name}"
}
subprojects {
    project.evaluationDependsOn(':app')
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

I see this "connectplay_app is stopped then this choice is shown"repeat " .I click "repeat" button but anything isn't changing. I continue to wait for loading app on emulator or device.Why is it like this?Please help me and light to me. Thanks for your comments and sorry for my mistakes.

Comment: I would recommend you run the android part of the project with Android Studio then open your Logcat section it will probably show you a more detailed error.

Comment: thank you @haliltprkk I will try